# Windows 8.1 32bit version upgrade to Windows 10 64bit version

Tags: memory, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-10-upgrade, cpu-architecture

I have a windows 8.1 32bit installation with 4GB of RAM and a x64 capable CPU. I've upgraded the RAM to 8GB and want to do the Windows 10 upgrade... as far as I'm aware the upgrade will do a like for like (32bit to 32bit)... If I do this and let Windows 10 activate... then do a clean x64 Windows 10 installation... will this work and activate correctly or does the hardware id hash contain architecture information (32bit x64 etc) and not allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as far as I'm aware the upgrade will do a like for like (32bit to
>   32bit)... If I do this and let Windows 10 activate... then do a clean
>   x64 Windows 10 installation... will this work

Yes, it will.

> or does the hardware id hash contain architecture information (32bit
>   x64 etc) and not allow this?

The hardware ID hash only contains details about your hardware, not about the software. You will be fine reinstalling 64 bit Windows 10

Comment: @DungeonMaster3000 if my answer helped, mind marking it as the solution (click the outline of the tick)?